# django-using same route in url path

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-urls

I was working on a project and I am a beginner in Django. I am passing user.id from template to URL for two things i.e one for profile update and one for a password reset. But it is going to only one URL whether I am clicking on profile update or password reset. I think the issue is I can not use the same routes in two URL paths.
here is my url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
path('login', views.login, name='login'),
path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
path('<int:user_id>/', views.chgprofile, name='chgprofile'),
path('<int:user_id>/', views.chgpassword, name='chgpassword'),
]
```

here is my template code which shows the two buttons:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'chgpassword' user.id %}">change password</a>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'chgprofile' user.id %}">update profile</a>
```

Is there any way to resolve this? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two following:

```
path('<int:user_id>/', views.chgprofile, name='chgprofile'),
path('<int:user_id>/', views.chgpassword, name='chgpassword'),
```

have the same pattern actually, Django always matches the first found `domain/ id between [0-9]`

So to deal with that, change the URLs patterns, make them different like;

```
path('update-profile/<int:user_id>/', views.chgprofile, name='chgprofile'),
path('update-password/<int:user_id>/', views.chgpassword, name='chgpassword'),
```

**Explanations**:

FIRST: In your templates, thanks to URL names, Django will generate the url with slashes as you used to do with raw HTML.

e.g: With `{% url 'chgpassword' user.id %}`, Django looks into your urls patterns, and finds the following `/update-password/<int:user_id>/` matches `{% url 'chgpassword' user.id %}` by replacing `user_id` with the id provided in template.

THEN: When you click on the HTML link, Django will look for the first match URL to `href='/update-password/ id_provided /`'... and call the view associated with it... That's why like you did, always called the same view, there were no different in urls, when Django loop through URLs, the first match was always the first found.

Comment: ok, thank you for helping. But do I need to change anything specifically in the templates as well?

Comment: Not really, Django will do the rest thanks to the URL names

Comment: That worked out really well. Thanks a lot for helping :)